# Array.indexOf shim without prototyping

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof, shim

What is a universal indexOf shim function that takes an array and a value to match, utilizing the native function where available?

Comment: You can modify the polyfill from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill

Comment: @FelixKling ^Without prototyping

Comment: ^ *"You can **modify** the polyfill [...]"*

Answer (score 0):

```
indexOf = (function() {
    if(typeof Array.prototype.indexOf === "function") {
        return function(haystack, needle, fromIndex){
            return haystack.indexOf(needle, fromIndex);
        };
    }
    return function(haystack, needle, fromIndex) {
        var l = haystack.length, 
            i = (typeof fromIndex === "undefined" ? 0 : (fromIndex < 0 ? l + fromIndex : fromIndex)), 
            index = -1;
        for(i; i < l; ++i) {
            if(haystack[i] === needle) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    };
})();
```

Use:

```
indexOf(["apples", "oranges", "bananas"], "apples");
//returns 0

indexOf(["oranges", "apples", "bananas"], "apples", 1);
//returns 1
```

Returns `-1` if not found.

Comment: You are missing the `fromIndex` parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Parameters.

Comment: You are still not handling negative indexes correctly: *"If the provided index value is a negative number, it is taken as the offset from the end of the array"*